# Deploy multiple projects in same solution

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I have a solution with 5 projects, I need to know if there's a way to right click on the solution, and have a deployment order for the projects inside, instead of deploying each one individually. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy your solution with all Projects inside, where they will be deployed based on the **Order of each Project Creation**.

- Simply, Right Click on Solution name and Select `Deploy Solution`.

[image]

I tried this at Solution with Two projects that worked properly and the OutPut of deployed solutions is

[image]

Also, you can specify order as the following

- Right Click on Solution > Project Build Order.

[image]

- Now Use the dependencies tab to change the order

[image]

**Note** : No way to `Retract` projects all in one. it will require retracting one by one.

**[Update Based on comments]**

You got `This dependency was added by the project system, and cannot be removed` due to you've added a reference to the one project from the other project. so in this case, you can't change project dependencies.

**A workaround to overcome that**

Try adding a new project to your solution, with no dependencies on other projects in your solution, and you'll see that the checkboxes are enabled.

Comment: how can I specify the order of the projects?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford I was added dependcies that specify order , now I added detail steps please check the updated answer

Comment: When I try to change the dependency, it says: This dependency was added by the project system, and cannot be removed.

Comment: What's the version of Visual Studio ?

Comment: visual studio 2013

Comment: I have updated my answer again based on your new error Please check it,